# How to create a spring web application using Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

Am new to Amazon Cloud service, I have to create a web application using Springs, Maven and Amazon DynamoDB. For that I have to create in Amazon Elastic Bean Services only or normally we can create a Maven spring project and include amazon dynamodb dependencies and deploy to Amazon EC2 cloud service. Now I really stuck with it? .. How to create a web app with Amazon enabled services?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`jcabi-dynamo`](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-dynamo/index.html), a simple object layer on top of Amazon SDK. For your Maven project I'd recommend to use [`jcabi-dynamodb-maven-plugin`](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-dynamodb-maven-plugin/index.html), which will help you to automate integration testing of your DynamoDB-empowered application.